# Retrieve info from a column with some empty cells from ODF Spreadsheet

Tags: spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

I have this ODF Spreadsheet on LibreOffice open, at it has one column with a lot of data that I wish to retrieve, however, I also have, a lot of white cells. Something like this:

```
emailA
emailB
--empty cell--
--empty cell--
emailC
--empty cell--
```

And I wish to have:

```
emailA
emailB
emailC
--empty cell--
--empty cell--
--empty cell--
```

The main point being that of exporting this to a csv file or something so that I use this addresses.

Can I have your help please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not aware of LibreOffice, but in Microsoft Office one can sort the workbook alphabetically with items in a single column. And that gets all your empty cells to top/bottom of the workbook.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. No easy still. We must go to "Data" then "Sort" then the tab "options" and finally, uncheck "Range Contains Column Labels"; uff... :)

Comment: If you need to do it all the time, create a macro and attach to a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Just sort the column and the blank entries will go after the entries containing data.